# How can I change the order of my questions in a survey?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

I have a survey that I'm building that generates questions/answers/etc based on an add/remove button. [Picture of the survey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fky7M.png)

I want to have the Move Up / Move Down buttons be able to change the ordering of the questions altogether so that if they, for example, hit move down on Question 1, it will swap the positions of question 1 and 2 and so on. I'm doing this currently in jQuery/javascript

Here is the relative code

```
<input type='button' value='Add Question' id='addButton'/>
        <input type='button' value='Remove Question' id='removeButton'/>
        <div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
            <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
                <input type="button" value="Move Up" id="MoveUpButton1" />
                <input type="button" value="Move Down" id="MoveDownButton1" />
                <label>Question #1 : </label>
                <input type='text' id='questionbox1'/> 
                <select id="choice1" class="choice">
                    <option value="text">Text Box</option>
                    <option value="radio">Radio Button</option>             
                    <option value="checkbox">Check Box</option>
                </select>
                <input type="button" value="Remove" id="remove1" class="remove" onclick="formSubmit(this.id)";/>
                <br/><label>Answer #1 : </label>
                <div id="Answers1" class="answers">
                         Option 1: <input type="text" id='answerbox11' name='answerbox1' class="answerbox"  value="" /><span><input type="text" id='hiddenanswerbox11' name='answerbox1' class="hiddenTextBoxes"  value=""  hidden="hidden"/></span>
                    <br/>Option 2: <input type="text" id='answerbox12' name='answerbox1' class="answerbox"  value="" /><span><input type="text" id='hiddenanswerbox12' name='answerbox1' class="hiddenTextBoxes"  value=""  hidden="hidden"/></span>
                    <br/>Option 3: <input type="text" id='answerbox13' name='answerbox1' class="answerbox"  value="" /><span><input type="text" id='hiddenanswerbox13' name='answerbox1' class="hiddenTextBoxes"  value=""  hidden="hidden"/></span>
                    <br/>Option 4: <input type="text" id='answerbox14' name='answerbox1' class="answerbox"  value="" /><span><input type="text" id='hiddenanswerbox14' name='answerbox1' class="hiddenTextBoxes"  value=""  hidden="hidden"/></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is the backend functionality for how the divs are created and what i'm trying to accomplish with the Move Up/Down buttons

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var counter = 2; //since question 1 is already displayed
var max_fields = 100;

$("#addButton").click(function () {

    if (counter > max_fields) {
        alert("Only " + max_fields + " Questions allowed");
        return false;
    }

    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
         .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

    newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<input type="button" value="Move Up" id="MoveUpButton' + counter + '" /> ' +
        '<input type="button" value="Move Down" id="MoveDownButton' + counter + '" /> ' +
        '<label>Question #' + counter + ' : </label>' +
        '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter +
        '" id="questionbox' + counter + '" value="" />' +
        ' <select id="choice' + counter + '" class="choice">' +
        '<option value="text">Text Box</option><option value="radio">Radio Button</option><option value="checkbox">Check Box</option></select>' +
        '<input type="button" value="Remove" id="remove' + counter + '" class="remove" onclick="formSubmit(this.id)";/>' +
        '<br/><label>Answer #' + counter + ' : </label>' +
        '<div id="Answers' + counter + '" class="answers">' +
        'Option 1: <input type="text" id="answerbox' + counter +
        '1" name="answerbox' + counter + '" class="answerbox" value="" />' +
        '<span><input type="text" id="hiddenanswerbox' + counter + '1" name="answerbox' + counter + '" class="hiddenTextBoxes"  value=""  hidden="hidden"/></span>' +
        '<br/>Option 2: <input type="text" id="answerbox' + counter +
        '2" name="answerbox' + counter + '" class="answerbox" value="" />' +
        '<span><input type="text" id="hiddenanswerbox' + counter + '2" name="answerbox' + counter + '" class="hiddenTextBoxes"  value=""  hidden="hidden"/></span>' +
        '<br/>Option 3: <input type="text" id="answerbox' + counter +
        '3" name="answerbox' + counter + '" class="answerbox" value="" />' +
        '<span><input type="text" id="hiddenanswerbox' + counter + '3" name="answerbox' + counter + '" class="hiddenTextBoxes"  value=""  hidden="hidden"/></span>' +
        '<br/>Option 4: <input type="text" id="answerbox' + counter +
        '4" name="answerbox' + counter + '" class="answerbox" value="" />' +
        '<span><input type="text" id="hiddenanswerbox' + counter + '4" name="answerbox' + counter + '" class="hiddenTextBoxes"  value=""  hidden="hidden"/></span></div>');
enter code here
    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
    counter++;
});
$(document).on("click", "#MoveUpButton1", function () { //hardcoded to get it working before adding in dynamic functionality
    var searchEles = $(this).attr('id');
    var endingNum = searchEles.slice(-1);
    var newTextBoxDiv = document.getElementById("TextBoxDiv" + endingNum);
    newTextBoxDiv.insertBefore("TextBoxDiv" + endingNum);
});

$(document).on("click", "#MoveUpButton1", function () {
    var searchEles = $(this).attr('id');
    var endingNum = searchEles.slice(-1);
    var newTextBoxDiv = document.getElementById("TextBoxDiv" + endingNum);
    newTextBoxDiv.insertAfter("TextBoxDiv" + endingNum);
    });
});
```

My main concerns are

1) I have no idea if it's correct to use newTextBoxDiv like that in the Move Up/Down functions, but I also don't know what else i'd use.
2) The big concern obviously is, is insertAfter and insertBefore the correct way to do this? It doesn't seem like it'd be the correct way to go about this, but I have no clue how i'd do this in general anyways. Plus I'm going to have to figure out how to update the numeric text for these once they've been switched because then it'd read 2, 1, 3 which would be a pain.

Am I close?

Comment: I would try something like creating a JSON array that contains the relevant information needed to populate the various form elements on the page, then switching them would be as easy as swapping the two indices, clearing all elements, and then re-generating them on the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to have the Move Up / Move Down buttons be able to change the
>   ordering of the questions altogether so that if they, for example, hit
>   move down on Question 1, it will swap the positions of question 1 and
>   2 and so on.

The layout below is greatly simplified from the layout in the question, but it contains the essential functionality:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

     $('input + span').click(function(){
     var listItem = $(this).parent();
     listItem.animate({top: '-36'}).prev().animate({top: '36'});
     setTimeout(function(){listItem.prev().before(listItem); $('li').removeAttr('style');}, 600);
     });

     $('input + span + span').click(function(){
     var listItem = $(this).parent();
     listItem.animate({top: '36'}).next().animate({top: '-36'});
     setTimeout(function(){listItem.next().after(listItem); $('li').removeAttr('style');}, 600);
     });

});
```

```css
li {
position: relative;
display: block;
height: 36px;
font-size: 18px;
line-height: 36px;
}

span {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
top: -2px;
font-size: 24px;
color: rgb(191,191,191);
transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

span:nth-of-type(2) {
top: 2px;
transform: rotate(90deg);
}

span:hover{
color: rgb(255,0,0);
text-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(191,0,0,0.8);
cursor: pointer;
}

li:first-of-type span:nth-of-type(1),
li:last-of-type span:nth-of-type(2) {
visibility: hidden;
}

ol {
counter-reset: listOrder;
}

li::before {
counter-increment: listOrder;
content: counter(listOrder) '. ';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
<ol>
<li><input type="text" name="text1" placeholder="text1" /> <span>&#10148;</span><span>&#10148;</span></li>
<li><input type="text" name="text2" placeholder="text2" /> <span>&#10148;</span><span>&#10148;</span></li>
<li><input type="text" name="text3" placeholder="text3" /> <span>&#10148;</span><span>&#10148;</span></li>
<li><input type="text" name="text4" placeholder="text4" /> <span>&#10148;</span><span>&#10148;</span></li>
<li><input type="text" name="text5" placeholder="text5" /> <span>&#10148;</span><span>&#10148;</span></li>
</ol>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a complete piece of code in the sense that its not fully-functional, however it does illustrate **how I would** write out a dynamic control such as the one outlined in the O.P.

Keep in mind that this is merely a suggestion, and would have been a comment if it weren't so long.

**here's ONE way** to  handle the storage of dynamic HTML elements by using Javascript equivalent of **custom types**  (AKA classes or instantiation)

```js
/*  create global array to store questions */
var questions = [];

/* create a Javascript class to describe what a Question is */
var Question = function(questionString, questionType, questionIndex, questionOptions) {
  this.questionString = questionString;
  this.questionType = questionType;
  this.questionIndex = questionIndex;
  this.questionOptions = questionOptions;

  /* implement  Question.generate_html()  to  generate HTML below */
  this.generate_html = function() {
    var returnhtml = document.createElement("div");
    var buttons = this.generate_move_buttons();
    $(buttons).appendTo(returnhtml);
    var group = document.getElementById("TextBoxesGroup");
    $(returnhtml).appendTo(group);
  }

  /*  Question.generate_move_buttons()  used by generate_html() */
  this.generate_move_buttons = function() {
    var downbutton = document.createElement("input");
    var upbutton = document.createElement("input");
    $(downbutton).prop("type", "button");
    $(upbutton).prop("type", "button");
    $(downbutton).prop("value", "Move Down");
    $(upbutton).prop("value", "Move Up");
    $(downbutton).prop("data-index", this.questionIndex);
    $(upbutton).prop("data-index", this.questionIndex);
    $(downbutton).addClass("downButton");
    $(upbutton).addClass("upButton");

    var returnval = upbutton.outerHTML + downbutton.outerHTML;

    return returnval;
  }

} /*  end of Question class */


/* create an instance of Question */
var new_question = new Question("question 1", "text", 1, ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"]);


/*  Store the generated html in the main array */
questions[0] = new_question.generate_html();

/*  create a new Question each time you click add button */
$("#addButton").on("click", function() {
  var ques = new Question("new question", $("#choice1").val(), questions.length, []);
  questions.push(ques.generate_html());
});

/* move index position up or down */
function swap(index1, index2) {
  questions[-1] = questions[index1];
  questions[-2] = questions[index2];
  questions[index1] = questions[-2];
  questions[index2] = questions[-1];

  /*  TODO: 
      erase TextBoxesGroup innerHTML and loop through questions, 
      appending questions[i]  to TextBoxesGroup */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' value='Add Question' id='addButton' />
<input type='button' value='Remove Question' id='removeButton' />
<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
  <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
    <input type="button" value="Move Up" id="MoveUpButton1" />
    <input type="button" value="Move Down" id="MoveDownButton1" />
    <label>Question #1 :</label>
    <input type='text' id='questionbox1' />
    <select id="choice1" class="choice">
      <option value="text">Text Box</option>
      <option value="radio">Radio Button</option>
      <option value="checkbox">Check Box</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="Remove" id="remove1" class="remove" onclick="formSubmit(this.id)" ;/>
    <br/>
    <label>Answer #1 :</label>
    <div id="Answers1" class="answers">
      Option 1:
      <input type="text" id='answerbox11' name='answerbox1' class="answerbox" value="" /><span><input type="text" id='hiddenanswerbox11' name='answerbox1' class="hiddenTextBoxes"  value=""  hidden="hidden"/></span>
      <br/>Option 2:
      <input type="text" id='answerbox12' name='answerbox1' class="answerbox" value="" /><span><input type="text" id='hiddenanswerbox12' name='answerbox1' class="hiddenTextBoxes"  value=""  hidden="hidden"/></span>
      <br/>Option 3:
      <input type="text" id='answerbox13' name='answerbox1' class="answerbox" value="" /><span><input type="text" id='hiddenanswerbox13' name='answerbox1' class="hiddenTextBoxes"  value=""  hidden="hidden"/></span>
      <br/>Option 4:
      <input type="text" id='answerbox14' name='answerbox1' class="answerbox" value="" /><span><input type="text" id='hiddenanswerbox14' name='answerbox1' class="hiddenTextBoxes"  value=""  hidden="hidden"/></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Enjoy and good luck.